# Parse cURL response WITHOUT using php in bash script

Tags: xml, parsing, curl, response

I'd like to know if there is a way to parse a cURL response without using PHP. Every example I've seen seems to explicitly use PHP.

- I'm calling cURL within a bash script.
- I cURL a URL and receive this XML response:

  `{"name":"callINSTANCETESTJob","id":10900,"status":"COMPLETED","message":"The job has finished."}`

My goal is to obtain the numeric value following `"id"` and setting it to a variable

**EDIT:**

my curl statement is as follows:

```
JOB_NAME=$1

request_url="https://127.0.0.1:8443/batch/$JOB_NAME"

curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/xml" $request_url | jq -r 'id.'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON with Unix tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is not XML, that is JSON. [try using `jq` to parse JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1955555/1067003), eg

`curl (...) | jq -r '.id'`

```
root@miner1:~# echo '{"name":"callINSTANCETESTJob","id":10900,"status":"COMPLETED","message":"The job has finished."}' | jq -r '.id'
10900
root@miner1:~#
```

Comment: Sorry for mistake. Thank you, what if I want to assign the results to a variable?

Comment: I've got it figured out. Thank you for the response. I've marked your answer as correct.